# **reading url from browser using qt**

Tags: qt

i'm trying to develop an application that listens to a specific port (for example 9999) in localhost.  how could i retrieve the URL when user types <127.0.0.1:9999/somedir> in his web browser?

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the URL you would have to implement some pieces of the HTTP protocol.

[This](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) is the official documentation of the HTTP protocol.

If you just want the path of the entered URL, you can parse just some of the request data. The following is an example of a HTTP request made by a browser:

```
GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
```

The first word at the first line is the command to be performed. Next, the path at the server, and than the protocol and its version. The next line (at this example) specify the host. This is used for example to a server to provide many web sites. This feature is called virtual host.

It is important to note that each line of the HTTP request and the response are separated by the `\r\n` characters.

Take a look at the [HTTP Protocol on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Http). It is a good start to implement some very basic functionality.

Comment: I know what is HTTP protocol and it's syntax (I've passed the university course "Computer Networks") but what I really want to know is does browser writes on socket that I established? take a look at a piece of my code:

    socket = server->nextPendingConnection();
    if(socket->state() == QTcpSocket::ConnectedState)
    {
       connect(socket,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(onReadyRead()));
    }
and inside the onReadyRead() slot the socket->bytesAvailable() function returns zero is there any other way that browser sends URL?

Comment: Yes, it does. Please, post more details of your code in your question so we can analyse what you've done and provide better answers. In the meantime, have you tried to implement the `readyRead` signal with the `atEnd` method instead? Check this URL to details: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractsocket.html#atEnd